# What is a word that means "Knowing that someone will not do something that they threaten to do"

Tags: single-word-requests

I was recently playing a manhunt game with my girlfriend and friends. After a while, she was the last alive and I threatened to break up with her to make her come out of her hiding spot.

But my friend that I captured told me that:

> She is a 'in...'

And I said "What?!". Then, he informed me that no matter what I say; she knows I will not do anything. What is this word?

Comment: Intelligent. If she ignores that threat, she's simply intelligent. She wins either way.

Answer (score 1):

If she does not believe anything you say, she could be called **incredulous**.

incredulous 
[in-krej-uh-luhs]
adjective
1. not credulous; disinclined or indisposed to believe; skeptical.
2. indicating or showing unbelief:
an incredulous smile.
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/incredulous

Answer (score 1):

If she was referring to what you said, it was an ***empty threat*** or an ***idle threat***: A threat that you have either no real intention of carrying out, or no actual capability to carry out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your wording, I'm not so clear on what you're looking for, but this might help: In a negotiation or similar exchange, when someone says she will do something without the intent of actually doing it (or the converse), she is said to be ***[bluffing](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/bluff)***.

Comment: The OP was bluffing.  His girlfriend, by refusing to act on the basis of his bluff, **called his bluff**.